# momentjs did not validate hour/minute/second

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a input support select date time picker with second. I use momentjs for convert value from input to date time format.

When I input value in input like this:

```
22-09-2019 15:ppp15:33
22-09-2019 1xx5:15:33
22-09-2019 15:15:test33
```

Moment object still show isValid.
Can you explain why isValid is true in this case? How can I do for validate hour/minute/second for this?

I used library ng-pick-datetime in angular 5.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to use strict mode [parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

> Moment's parser is very forgiving, and this can lead to undesired/unexpected behavior.
>
> As of version **2.3.0**, you may specify a boolean for the last argument to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires that the format and input match exactly, *including delimeters*.

See also [Strict Mode](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/) guide, here a live sample:

```js
['22-09-2019 15:ppp15:33',
'22-09-2019 1xx5:15:33',
'22-09-2019 15:15:test33',
'22-09-2019 15:15:33'].forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item, moment(item, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss', true).isValid() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```